# How to find a map in list of maps where a key has a certain value in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a `List[Map[String, Any]` and I want to return the map which has a certain value for one of the keys.  Here's an obfusticated example:

```scala
val items: List[Map[String, Any]] = List(Map("name" -> "A", "size" -> 50), Map("name" -> "B", "size" -> 75), Map("name" -> "C", "size" -> 100)))

val mapB: Map[String, Any] = items.find(|m| m("name") == "B") // Psuedo code
```

`mapB` would be `Map("name" -> "B", "size" -> 75)`.

**Bonus Question**

Is there also a way to return the value of another key instead of the whole `Map`?

For example, if I only wanted the `size` value (75) for `name` `B`?  I know I can extract it from the `Map` as a two-step operation, but if there's another more idiomatic way, I'd be interested in learning it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find()` returns an `Option` in case what you're looking for cannot be found.

```
val mapB: Option[Map[String, Any]] = items.find(_("name") == "B") //safe
```

or

```
val mapB: Map[String, Any] = items.find(_("name") == "B").get //unsafe, might throw
```

---

To retrieve the `size` value from the first `Map` where `"name" -> "B"` you could do something like this.

```
val sz :Any = items.find(m => m.get("name").contains("B")
                           && m.get("size").nonEmpty).fold(0:Any)(_("size"))
```

Note that `sz` is type `Any` because that's what the type of the `Map` values. Which means that you'd have to cast it (discouraged) to type `Int` before you can do anything useful with it.

Avoid type `Any`. It's a sure sign that you're going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Even safer to do `find(_.get("name").contains("B"))` in case one of the maps doesn't have "name" as a key.

Comment: @jwvh Yes, I'd love to avoid `Any` as it's arduous to deal with.  However, that's what the Jackson JSON parser returns.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing jwvh's answers *(and using Tim's suggestion to improve safety)*.
Here is a function that addresses your bonus question.

```
def findAndGet(maps: List[Map[String, Any]], condition: (String, Any), key: String): Option[Any] = condition match {
  case (k, v) =>
    maps.find(map => map.get(k).contains(v)).flatMap(map => map.get(key))
}
findAndGet(maps = items, condition = ("name", "B"), key = "size")
// res0: Option[Any] = Some(75)
```

*BTW, a `Map[String, Any]` makes me thing you are dealing with **JSONs**, have you take a look to any of the Scala libraries for dealing with them in a more "typesafe" way?, having an `Any` in your code should always be an alarm that something is wrong*.

Comment: Yes, the `Map[String, Any]` is coming from the Jackson JSON parser.  I tried switching to the Play JSON library, though I couldn't get it to work with my Spark `sbt` project.

Comment: @EdwardJ.Stembler If you know the schema of the **JSON**, I would recommend you to create a _case class_ that represents them. **Spark** is capable of reading and casting those to a `Dataset[YourClass]`, if you don't need them inside **Spark** perse, you should give a look to [**Circe**](https://circe.github.io/circe/), you should only need a `decode[List[YourClass](json)` call ;)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the JSON library I'm using (JSON4s with Jackson) supports case class decoding as well. I may look into this if I can get it working quickly. My JSON is nested but it's not that deep.  I know how to represent nested Maps, but I'm not sure about case classes.  Can case classes accept inline nesting, or is it done via composition with another case class definition? Are case classes typically defined in their own files?  Also, not sure how to represent if a list of things can be empty; if that even matters.

Comment: @EdwardJ.Stembler Usually I just create a _case class_ for each **complex type**, that means, any nested document is another _case class_, if you have an array of documents, then use a **List** of the nested document type. Usually these decoders can handle arbitrary deep derivation. Regarding the files. Scala allows you to define multiple types in one file _(usually the file is named in lower case)_, I tend to put all related _case classes_ in one file _(but that is just a matter of preference)_.

Comment: For the empty case, if your type is a **List** it can be empty, if the field can be `null` these decoders usually can use the [**Option** ADT](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html), then you have a `Some[T]` if the field is present and a `None` if `null`, some decoder allow also default values to use in case the field is `null`, so you don't have to deal with **Options**.